# Captcha nuget package always Valid on ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, captcha

I've installed the [captcha plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Captcha/) and followed the setup instructions.  The captcha renders perfectly on the page but when submit the form, the ModelState.IsValid is always true, no matter what I enter.  Obviously, if captcha won't validate then it's not much good to me.

Here's my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [CaptchaValidation("CaptchaCode", "SampleCaptcha", "Incorrect CAPTCHA code!")]
    public ActionResult Register(AccountModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // TODO: Captcha validation failed, show error message
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Captcha validation passed, proceed with protected action
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And here's my view:

```
<link href="@BotDetect.Web.CaptchaUrls.Absolute.LayoutStyleSheetUrl" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form class="form-horizointal" action="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First Name"})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "control-label", placeholder = "Last Name" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { placeholder = "Last Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "col-sm-2 control-label", placeholder = "Email"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {placeholder = "Email"})
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @{ MvcCaptcha sampleCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("SampleCaptcha"); }
        @Html.Captcha(sampleCaptcha)
        @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        captcha goes here
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working for me?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which captcha plugin? One of them makes it imperitive your VM inherits from the library's model (in which case that could be the problem--MVC doesn't know about the other propert(y/ies) and has no reason to validate it). **EDIT** Scratch that, The link is almost the first word. Time for sleep me thinks.

Comment: Update: I've done a few things like add the captcha fields as model properties and on the last pass it magically started working.  I'm not sure why though.  :-/

Comment: Did you do rest part of instructions from http://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/howto/asp.net-mvc-captcha.html which include change in routing?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it's the same problem. I've got a botdetect captcha in a modal popup. It' works ok until passes the first validation ok, after then it's always true so i added a samplecaptcha.Reset() and the Model.IsValid is false again when it's not valid.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    MvcCaptcha sampleCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("SampleCaptcha");
    sampleCaptcha.Reset();
}
```

[etc]

Comment: A Reset seems like a temporary workaround, and it may not be reliable in the long term.  I would suggest digging/debugging into the captcha and figuring out what is going on.  If you can post code or create a fiddle using something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc then I can try to help investigate for you.

Answer (score 1):

//I had the same problem with you, but i solved it with this way

```
    public ActionResult RegistrationComp(NewRegistration data, bool captchaValid)
    {
        try
        {
            captchaValid = MvcCaptcha.Validate(data.CaptchaID, data.CaptchaCode, data.CurrentInstanceID);

            MvcCaptcha.ResetCaptcha(data.CaptchaID);

            if (!captchaValid)
                return this.Json("false");
            else
                return this.Json("true");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.Json("false");
        }
    }
```

in RegistrationModel add properties : CaptchaID ,CaptchaCode the user input,CurrentInstanceID

**cshtml**

```
MvcCaptcha exampleCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("C");

exampleCaptcha.UserInputID = "CC";

<script>
 $.post("@Url.Action("RegistrationComp", "Authentication")", { CaptchaCode: $("#CC").val() , CaptchaID: '@exampleCaptcha.CaptchaId',CurrentInstanceID: '@exampleCaptcha.CurrentInstanceId' }, function (data) {});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that out.